# How vulnerability scanners identify version of services on targets

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners

I would like to know that how vulnerability scanners identify the version of services running on the target after identifying the service by the port number.

Comment: Do you mean banner grabbing?

Answer (score 1):

## How Fingerprinting works

For every service fingerprinting would be done differently, generally, it works by finding differences between the implementations, and using them to detect the version of the software, I have included a few simple examples:

### SSH

If you run the following command:

```
nc HOST 22
```

You can see that the first thing that a server sends is a string identifying it's version, such as:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
```

From this you can get the version

### HTTP

If you run the following command:

```
curl -v URL > /dev/null
```

You can see that the server sends many headers, one of which is likely to look like this:

```
< Server: cloudflare
```

This can show you the server if it has not been changed, and possibly the plugins running also

### Wordpress

Looking at the feed available at `/feed/` gives an xml file with the following tag:

```
<generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.9.2</generator>
```

If this is disabled then differences in the readme can be used to detect the version instead

Comment: short answer is: the service tells you what version it is

Comment: @jrtapsell Thank you so much for the detailed answer.